# Rollback a particular migration?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is it possible to rollback a particular migration in Laravel?

For example:

If I make four migration like M1, M2, M3 and M4 and later I decided to add more fields in M2. Can I roll back all the way directly to M2? or just simply edit existing M2 migration file directly?

Comment: Migration 5 should be adding new columns

Comment: I agree with @Farkie, it's better to create a new migration that will alter the table you created on M2 adding the new fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice would be @Farkie's comment, create a new migration.
But if you really want to hack, the way Laravel rollbacks migrations is like this: on migrations tables there is a column called 'batch' so when rollback is executed all records with the biggest batch number will be rollbacked and the records of the rollbacked migrations will be deleted from migrations table.

A way to hack could be:

If migrations table is like:

```
migration   |   batch
===========================
M1               |    1
M2               |    1
M3               |    1
M4               |    1
```

Edit the table so it looks like

```
migration   |   batch
===========================
M1               |    1
M2               |    2
M3               |    2
M4               |    2
```

So when rolling back it will rollback M2, M3 and M4, do your changes and migrate again